# htaccess RewriteRule with 3 rules and 2 different PHP Files ( ERROR )

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, expression

I have 3 rules, but when the variable is blank (example.com/) I need it to load the index.php, but the 2nd rule and 3rd rule never get executed

how do I solve it?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(PanelControl|Home|Pages|Gallery|Password)?$ panel.php?module=$1 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&subpage=$2 [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]
```

Note: 1st Rule works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in first rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^PanelControl|Home|Pages|Gallery|Password/?$ panel.php?module=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This is wrong regex as `^` will be applied for `PanelControl` only and `/?$` will be for `Password`